# Proguard: Specify name of obfuscated class

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation, android-proguard

Does Proguard have an option to specify names of obfuscated classes?

Something to configure in proguard.flag file or adding mymap.map file with list of classes and names as below?

com.myclasses.MyClass -> com.priv.mc

Answer (score 1):

You can add your own mapping file adding:

```
-applymapping yourMappingFile
```

to your proguard-rules.pro file.

and inside use:

```
com.myclasses.MyClass -> com.priv.mc
```

To avoid creating whole file by yourself just use:

```
-printmapping mapping.txt
```

build your project (the file mappint.txt will be created) and than just edit records that you find important.

Comment: Thank you muminers!

Comment: Thank you muminers! But when I added flag:
-applymapping yourMappingFile
and create yourMappingFile with com.myclasses.MyClass -> com.priv.mc nothing has changed. I need to do full mapping for class like :
com.myclasses.MyClass -> com.priv.mc:
fierstField -> aa
secondField -> bb
............
to change name of obfuscated class.

I'd like to build obfuscated jar in first time and specify some names of classes. Not all of them. But this option : applymapping seams working only with some previous obfuscation.

Comment: From ProGuard manual:
The -applymapping option then makes sure the ProGuard part of the code gets the previously produced obfuscation mapping.